# Vue3: understand how import data from axios (after small used vue2)

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I  get data from Axios's request, but can't transfer results into this. data (but I can transfer data in vue2)

```
Vue.createApp({
    data () {
      return {
        axiosData: [],
        statusDataExchange: [],
        newArraywithDiscount: [],
        myPoints: userPoints

      }
    },

    methods: {
      apicheck: async function fetchApi () {
        // i trying used here "var self = this" but this not helped me (but helped in vue2)
        await axios.get('itemsConn.php').then(response => { // response data - ok
          this.axiosData = response.data
          console.log(this.axiosData) // it's good here too
        })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      },
      mounted () {
        this.apicheck()
        console.log(this.axiosData) // return empty proxy
      }
    }
  }
).mount('#app')
```

I trying to move Axios request to mounted(), outside from Vue app, but Axios's result always stays inside the request.

That works correctly in Vue2 when I can place Axios request into mount() and that is work.

```
mounted() {
  axios.get(`https://api.requestExample.com`)
    .then(response => (this.statusData = response.data.data[wot_idAPI]));
},
```

The documentation for Vue3 describes changes to the date with wrapping in a proxy, but I do not understand how to use it.
I am using a connection to Vue through a script from CDN without creating a project in CLI or other methods.

How i can transfer response.data to this.axiosData ?

Answer (score 0):

This breaks reactivity, as you just overwriting the array.

```
this.axiosData = response.data
```

Try this:

```
this.axiosData.splice(0) // remove all elelemts of erray
this.axiosData.push(...response.data) // assuming data is array
```